# How to make google maps work with react

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I'm trying to Map with a SearchBox in react but I'm not sure what I am missing from this code below. I've never used google maps before and the docs are really confusing. The error I get is that google is no defined and I'm assuming I need to import something but research has proven to be useless. I got the code from https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps.

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const { compose, withProps, lifecycle } = require("recompose");
const {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,  
} = require("react-google-maps");
const { SearchBox } = require("react-google- 
maps/lib/components/places/SearchBox");

const MapWithASearchBox = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 





 key=AIzaSyC4R6AN7SmujjPUIGKdyao2Kqitzr1kiRg&v=3.exp&libraries
 =geometry,draw 
     ing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  }),
  lifecycle({
    componentWillMount() {
      const refs = {}

      this.setState({
        bounds: null,
        center: {
         lat: 41.9, lng: -87.624
        },
        markers: [],
        onMapMounted: ref => {
          refs.map = ref;
        },
        onBoundsChanged: () => {
          this.setState({
            bounds: refs.map.getBounds(),
            center: refs.map.getCenter(),
          })
        },
        onSearchBoxMounted: ref => {
          refs.searchBox = ref;
        },
        onPlacesChanged: () => {
          const places = refs.searchBox.getPlaces();
          const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

          places.forEach(place => {
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport)
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location)
            }
          });
          const nextMarkers = places.map(place => ({
            position: place.geometry.location,
          }));
          const nextCenter = _.get(nextMarkers, '0.position', 
          this.state.center);

          this.setState({
            center: nextCenter,
            markers: nextMarkers,
          });
          // refs.map.fitBounds(bounds);
        },
      })
    },
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props =>
  <GoogleMap
    ref={props.onMapMounted}
    defaultZoom={15}
    center={props.center}
    onBoundsChanged={props.onBoundsChanged}
   >
    <SearchBox
      ref={props.onSearchBoxMounted}
      bounds={props.bounds}
      controlPosition={google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT}
      onPlacesChanged={props.onPlacesChanged}
     >
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Customized your placeholder"
        style={{
          boxSizing: `border-box`,
          border: `1px solid transparent`,
          width: `240px`,
          height: `32px`,
          marginTop: `27px`,
          padding: `0 12px`,
          borderRadius: `3px`,
          boxShadow: `0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)`,
          fontSize: `14px`,
          outline: `none`,
          textOverflow: `ellipses`,
        }}
       />
     </SearchBox>
    {props.markers.map((marker, index) =>
       <Marker key={index} position={marker.position} />
    )}
  </GoogleMap>
);

<MapWithASearchBox />
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by linter, you need to explicitly read `google` global variable from `window` by adding the below line to the top of your file:

```
const google = window.google;
```

or to disable linter:

```
/*global google*/
```